# Keep Google Maps marker in centre of map while dragged?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'd like to display some crosshairs in the very centre of a Google Map.

Currently I have code like this:

```
        var mapCentre = map.getCenter();
        reticleMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: mapCentre,
            map: map,
            icon: reticleImage, 
            shape: reticleShape,
            optimized: false,
            zIndex: 5
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed',
           function(){reticleMarker.setPosition(map.getCenter());});
```

Works great on a desktop, but not on mobile. On mobile the crosshairs don't stay in the centre of the map while the user's finger is dragging the map.

Using a `drag` event listener doesn't work any better.

Could anyone suggest how to deal with this in mobile browsers? (For reference, I'm seeing this problem in an Android browser.)

I'm thinking perhaps I should display the crosshairs in CSS, rather than as a map marker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm thinking perhaps I should display the crosshairs in CSS, rather than as a map marker?

I've used a similar approach to great effect. You can put any HTML you want in the maps container, Google Maps wont mind.

Comment: Unfortunately, the crosshairs create a dead spot in the map if displayed as an image - they look good, but the user can't drag the map if they touch anywhere covered by the crosshairs. So I need an alternative solution...

Comment: In my case I used HTML div's to 'draw' a bounding box onto the pane. Drawing a crosshair shouldn't be too hard. If you do this the chance of hitting the crosshair when you start dragging is minimal. A perfect solution would require you to either make the browser ignore the crosshair or forward all events on it to the underlying map. This is very complex.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but someone suggested using `pointer-events:none;` on the CSS image, and that solved the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178669/display-png-over-google-maps-without-creating-dead-spot - Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Richard this is an accepted answer? Really? Any real solution out there?

Comment: @Sharky since this question is quite old, and applies to an older version of the GMaps API you might be better off asking it anew.