# Display PNG over Google Maps without creating dead spot?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I'm overlaying a (mostly transparent) PNG on Google Maps using CSS, but it's creating a large dead spot on the map where the user can't drag the map.

Could anyone suggest how to get round this?

The obvious solution would be to use a marker overlay, but I can't do this - see [Keep Google Maps marker in centre of map while dragged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166391/keep-google-maps-marker-in-centre-of-map-while-dragged)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `pointer-events:none;` to the CSS for the overlay image, and see if this allows you to click through the image to the map.  I tested this in Mozilla Firefox 6. You can click through the semi-transparent image and select the text:
http://jsfiddle.net/tJQWx/

Comment: Great stuff! Unfortunately it seems to work in non-IE browsers only.
 Reference: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)

Comment: can anybody please explain about above jsfiddle.....

thanks in advance